# 2020 MacBook Air, no mouse or trackpad control when dual booting Linux

Tags: mac, unix, dual-boot

I've recently tried to dual boot macOS Monterey and Linux onto my Mac, but it's not going too well. I've tried different types of Linux (Mint and  Ubuntu all the newest versions) and have created the bootable USB using Balena Etcher. Everything works fine up until it actually loads in, where I cannot move my mouse or use my keyboard. I've read somewhere that this may be due to the T2 security chip but I don't know if that's it or how to get around that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do the distributions of Linux you are trying to use claim support for that hardware?

Comment: Is this a M1 MacBook Air ?